# make e-mail updates better and I'd like to receive them at least once a day

Tags: feature-request

First please understand that I've searched on this website and read through possible duplicates. I have eliminated all of these other questions as either outdated by a year or more or irrelevant.

A week or two ago I had posted on how stack overflow account administration is confusing but this post was removed. Here is the URL even though it was removed (maybe you admins can see it but I can't)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106354/stack-overflow-account-administration-is-confusing

I have stackoverflow registered to a gmail account. I rarely, if ever, get my updates or they take a very long time. I don't understand why.  Take for example this question
[C - 'char **' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[6]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524070/c-char-differs-in-levels-of-indirection-from-char-6)
The answers are from September 23rd at the latest. However only today did I receive an e-mail notifying me of new comments/answers.

I find stackoverflow confusing. I don't say this to be mean but I just don't get why it isn't more intuitive when it comes to e-mail. Most forums have a subscribe feature. You can subscribe to a thread's daily update or you can be notified immediately if you choose. I understand from what I've read that there is no intention of supporting the latter but how about at least the former.

Basically what I'd expect is every post I've favorited to receive daily updates on. So if there was some system that say checked all my favorited threads, and threads for which I'm the OP (ie questions I asked), and then sent me a list of those threads that have changed in some way. And (feature request) if possible the context of the answer or comment if it's brief so I wouldn't have to go to the website if not necessary.

So is that what stackoverflow already does? Am I just the exception? My e-mail settings are set to e-mail from my inbox daily apparently.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why

Because the intended usage model of Stack Overflow is that you *visit the website*.

> Most forums have a subscribe feature

That's nice for them. Stack Overflow, however, is not a forum.

<sub>Also, [Jeff hates email](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/is-email-efail.html).</sub>